# synchronized countdown timer- android development

Tags: java, android

I have an app that has one countdown timer that should show up the same for every user when they open the app. In order to do this, I have based the time that the users' phones show on Epoch time. I do the following calculations to (what I thought would...) ensure that each phone shows the same time, and that the countdown clock is continuous and accurate. However, every time I open the app up, the clock is at a totally different time, when I think it should be continuously counting down and resetting. What's wrong? I have included my code below:

```
private static final int COUNTDOWN_DURATION = 30; //time in seconds 
private static final long BASE_TIME = 1470729402L; //an arbitrary Epoch time that I have picked as a reference point

private TextView tvTimer;
private Long currentTimeMillis;
private int finalTime;
private boolean firstTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //set up basics
    ...

    //set up timer
    tvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
    firstTime = true;
    setCurrentTime();
}

private void setCurrentTime() {
    currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currentTimeSecs = currentTimeMillis/1000;
    long timeDiff = currentTimeSecs - BASE_TIME;

    //determines what spot the countdown timer is at when the app is started
    finalTime = (int) (timeDiff % COUNTDOWN_DURATION);
    resetTimer();
}

public void resetTimer(){
    if (firstTime) {
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(finalTime *      1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimer.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " ");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                resetTimer();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        firstTime = false;
    }
    else {
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_DURATION * 1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimer.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " ");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                resetTimer();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
}
```